# jquery custom transition like uncover - need to set direction on the fly

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

Quick jquery cycle question:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.uncover = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    var d = opts.direction || 'left';
    var w = $cont.css('overflow','hidden').width();
    var h = $cont.height();
    opts.before.push(function(curr, next, opts) {
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts,true,true,true);
        if (d == 'right')
            opts.animOut.left = w;
        else if (d == 'up')
            opts.animOut.top = -h;
        else if (d == 'down')
            opts.animOut.top = h;
        else
            opts.animOut.left = -w;
    });
    opts.animIn.left = 0;
    opts.animIn.top = 0;
    opts.cssBefore.top = 0;
    opts.cssBefore.left = 0;
};
```

This is the jquery cycle uncover transition.

I would like to decide on the fly if the effect direction should be up or down.

- If current slide is lets say 2 of 5 and I click on page nav linking to slide 1 then it should be 'up'.
- If current slide is 2 of 5 and I click on page navigation linking to slide 5 then the direction should be 'down'

From the logic part this seems to be done by a simple "if" statement but I've tried and couldnt really get the job done.

Any hints would be appreciated!

One more thing: I know that there is something like scrollVert - but it does not fill my needs. I need to uncover in both ways (up/down) almost like scrollVert works but not exacly in the same way.

As an addition, scrollVert is:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.scrollVert = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    $cont.css('overflow','hidden');
    opts.before.push(function(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
        if (opts.rev)
            fwd = !fwd;
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts);
        opts.cssBefore.top = fwd ? (1-next.cycleH) : (next.cycleH-1);
        opts.animOut.top = fwd ? curr.cycleH : -curr.cycleH;
    });
    opts.cssFirst.top = 0;
    opts.cssBefore.left = 0;
    opts.animIn.top = 0;
    opts.animOut.left = 0;
};
```

Im trying to change the scrollvert function but in the uncover there is an if d == ... and dunno how to transport that condition from uncover to scrollvert

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which Slide is currently being shown and Which one is next using [$.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in `uncover` transition like following

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.uncover = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    var d = opts.direction || 'left';
    var w = $cont.css('overflow','hidden').width();
    var h = $cont.height();
    opts.before.push(function(curr, next, opts) {
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts,true,true,true);
        // find index of Current slide
        var curIndex = $slides.index(curr) + 1;// as it's 0 based
        // find index of Next Slide 
        var nextIndex = $slides.index(next) + 1;
        // now set d based on this two values
        if(curIndex == 2 && nextIndex == 1)
           d = 'up';
        if(curIndex == 2 && nextIndex == 5)
           d = 'down';
        // add as many condition as you want
        if (d == 'right')
            opts.animOut.left = w;
        else if (d == 'up')
            opts.animOut.top = -h;
        else if (d == 'down')
            opts.animOut.top = h;
        else
            opts.animOut.left = -w;
    });
    opts.animIn.left = 0;
    opts.animIn.top = 0;
    opts.cssBefore.top = 0;
    opts.cssBefore.left = 0;
};
```

I hope You can now figure out what you want from above code. Or let me know if you want otherwise.